# how to arrange form

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I have a few buttons in a visualForce page that are connected to functions. Most of these buttons work fine, but for some, they won't refer to the Apex file. I believe it has something to do with the apex:form tag but I'm not sure how or how to arrange them to solve the problem.
This is the VisualForce page that is giving me the error (I cant seem to be able to upload the entire thing).

```
<apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock id="detailPage">

            <apex:pageBlocksection rendered="{!isAccountSelected}" title="Details">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Name </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputLabel >{!selectedAccount.Name}</apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Address </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!selectedAccount.billingstreet}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >City </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!selectedAccount.billingCity}"></apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Country </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!selectedAccount.billingCountry}"></apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:pageBLockSectionItem>
                <table> 
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveEntry}" /></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteEntry}"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlocksection>

            <apex:pageBlocksection rendered="{!addNew}" title="Add new Account">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Name </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!searchQuery}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Address </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputTextarea value="{!address}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >City </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!city}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem><br/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Country </apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!country}"></apex:inputText>
                </apex:pageBLockSectionItem>
                <table> 
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:commandButton value="Save Entry" action="{!saveEntry}"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </table> 
            </apex:pageBlocksection>

         </apex:pageBlock>
         </apex:form>
```

The buttons under the second pageblocksection work like a charm but the ones under the first block don't fire thhe functions assigned to them in Apex. What am I doing wrong? How to arrange the apex:forms?
Thanks!

Comment: The `apex:form` What happens when you click the buttons that aren't working properly? If you have developer console open, do you get a debug log?

Comment: Setup the debug logs and see if you are getting any error on clicking Button.
SetUp --> Logs--> Debug logs --> click on new and your name --> save.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer to the question.. This is to see the debug logs. I would suggest you add it as comment instead

Comment: Well, a debug message appears, but my System.Debug string isn't listed.

Comment: Nope. Nothing happens, no errors, nothing. It just doesn't go into my Apex reference function.

Comment: Add a `<apex:pagemessages />` tag at the top of your page to make sure that you see any errors. What debug message is appearing?

Comment: I added that tag but I get no errors whatsoever.

Comment: I just tested out your code using just the buttons and none of the input/output fields. All the buttons are worked correctly.

Comment: @Raviteja I've converted your answer into a comment. When you're asking questions to or suggesting approaches to better analyse an issue consider using comments. Answers are preferred for more solid answers.

Comment: I got a bit further: it because "{!isAccountSelected}" is false when the page is loaded. If I set it to true at the start, it works normally.